# Ember.js - Resource index route without dynamic segment

Tags: ember.js

How can I define routes like this:

- /users  *(show all users)*
- /users/:user_id *(show specific user)*

  - /users/:user_id/projects *(show projects of specific user)*

I currently have this configured:

```
@resource 'users', path: '/users/:user_id', ->
    @route 'projects'
```

But the problem is that I can't access `/users` (there's no such route). The `UsersIndexRoute`  is referring to `/users/:user_id`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would be best doing something like:

```
this.resource('users', function() {
    this.resource('user', {path: '/:user_id'}, function() {
        this.resource('projects');
    });
});
```

This will generate (or if you've defined them; use):

- A `UsersRoute` with URL `/users`, a `UsersController` and a `User` model where you would load all users.
- A `UserRoute` with URL `/users/:user_id`, a `UserController` and the same `User` model where you would load an individual user's details.
- A `ProjectsRoute` with URL `/users/:user_id/projects`, a `ProjectsController` and a `Project` model where you would load the user projects.

[JSBin example](http://jsbin.com/ucanam/542/edit) showing this in action.

See [here](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/defining-your-routes/) for more information on defining routes and what Ember will expect to see (or generate for you).

Comment: I replaced the routes, following your example, but I get this error: `More context objects were passed than there are dynamic segments for the route: users.index`

Comment: Change the route in your `linkTo` helper to `user.index` instead of `users.index`

Comment: Great! That works now, but when I for example visit `/users/123`, I expect to be able to do `App.User.find(params.user_id)` in the `UserIndexRoute`, but params is an empty hash.